# How to set transition none for a specific css property

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have an element with the transition property

```
// app.css
.myBtn{
   width: 100px;
   transition: all 6s ease-out;
   background: blue;
}

.myBtn:hover{
   width: 300px;
   background-color: green;
}
```

Now, I want to set **transition:none** only for **background-color** property.

**Note:** I cannot change **app.css** file code, I have to write on some other file.

Any helpful answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could override the transition property value leaving out background but you would have to specify each property you do want to transition.

```
.myBtn{
    transition-property: width, height... etc;
}
```